# LibGdx Input data in a textfield

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a textfield using scene2d but don't know how to save user input. this is what i have and it just draws the textfield.

```
     txtUsername = new TextField("", mSkin);
     txtUsername.setMessageText("test");
     txtUsername.setPosition(30, 30);
     mStage.addActor(txtUsername);
```

Answer (score 4):

TextField has a method called getText(), it may never be null but may return an empty string.

```
txtUsername = new TextField("", mSkin);
txtUsername.setMessageText("test");
txtUsername.setPosition(30, 30);
mStage.addActor(txtUsername);
String test = txtUsername.getText();
System.out.println(test);
```

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextField.html#text